# Admob Interstitial Singleton Pattern java.lang.NullPointerException:

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, singleton

I am using **Singleton** pattern to show Admob Interstitial. In fact no problem in emulator. I tried in different smartphones no problem. Everything works well. But when it comes to Google Play Developer Console I am getting these errors.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2200)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2250)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:139)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1200)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5105)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:792)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:608)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at x.y.z.ViewItemActivity.onCreate (ViewItemActivity.java:48)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:5275)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1087)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2164)
```

**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
      at x.y.z.ViewItemActivity.onCreate (ViewItemActivity.java:48)**

Line 48 in ViewItemActivity:

```
if (ad.isLoaded()) {//Line 48
            ad.show();
        }
```

Let me show, AdManager Class and usage

**AdManager Class:**

```
package x;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import x.y.z.R;
import x.y.z.app.App;

public class AdManager {


    static InterstitialAd ad;
    private Context ctx;

    public AdManager(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public void createAd() {
        // Create an ad.
        ad = new InterstitialAd(ctx);
        ad.setAdUnitId(App.getResourses().getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit));

        final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        // Load the interstitial ad.
        ad.loadAd(adRequest);

       // Log.d("admobshowing","asdf");
    }

    public InterstitialAd getAd() {
        return ad;
    }
}
```

**I request in MainActivity in OnCreate:**

```
AdManager adManager = new AdManager(MainActivity.this);
adManager.createAd();
```

**I show it in another activity - ViewItemActivity - before setContentView:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AdManager adManager = new AdManager(ViewItemActivity.this);
    InterstitialAd ad = adManager.getAd();
    if (ad.isLoaded()) {
        ad.show();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_item);

....

....
```

**I request again when user press back button: - ViewItemActivity**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
AdManager adManager = new AdManager(ViewItemActivity.this);
adManager.createAd();
super.onBackPressed();
}
```

As a result, I don't get error in emulator or real smartphone when I try individually but in Google Play Developer console I get tens of null pointer exception. How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the singleton pattern is appropriate for your use case. You are attempting to create a new ad per context, so there is no benefit to persisting the ad across instantiations of AdManager. You can change your AdManager to the following and remove all calls to `createAd`.

```
public class AdManager {

    private InterstitialAd ad;
    private Context ctx;

    public AdManager(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    private void createAd() {
        // Create an ad.
        ad = new InterstitialAd(ctx);
        ad.setAdUnitId(App.getResourses().getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit));

        final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        // Load the interstitial ad.
        ad.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    public InterstitialAd getAd() {
        if (ad == null) {
            createAd();
        }
        return ad;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I could do like this, show rate will be approximately 0. Firstly, I want request then show after seconds. (not immediately)

Comment: Why my code does not work in other smartphones when works well for my real smartphone and emulator? It is the most important question

Comment: If you want to create a local reference to the ad in your activity's `onCreate` that would satisfy your issue. As to why it is not working, you probably have a race condition which is often introduced by this singleton approach. There is no validation in your code after you call `getAd()`, which means you expose yourself to NPEs like you are seeing. The above guarantees a non-null ad is returned from `getAd()`.